# Add MetadataType to derived class in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a Class called

```
public partial class Contact
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have another Class called

```
public partial class Person : Contact
{
   public string Occupation { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I have my third class called Person which is declared Partial and Fourth class called PersonMetaData used to declare annotations

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
    public partial class Person : Contact
    {

    }

    public class PersonMetadata
    {
         [StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameLength",   
         ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(BasicErrors))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameRequired",  
          ErrorMessageResourceType  = typeof(BasicErrors))]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameLength", 
         ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(BasicErrors))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType 
         = typeof(BasicErrors))]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

In my MVC View, I have made a strongly typed page based on  Person? The problem is, required and string length validations do not work. This problem occurs when inheriting a class and creating a partial class to reference the MetadataType.

If there is no inheritance then MetadataType works fine when calling a Partial Class.

Any Solutions when using MetadataType for derived class and using partial with it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It was the problem in MVC2. However it works in MVC3. See the following article :

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538360/asp-net-mvc-2-rc2-the-client-side-validation-does-not-work-with-overridden-properties

Answer (score 1):

Remove that partial and try this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
public partial class Person : Contact
{
   public string Occupation { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
}
```